# Why when maximizing a window it does not cover everything?

Tags: unity, gnome, firefox, budgie

I've just installed Ubuntu Budgie. I was used to the latest Ubuntu that didn't used Gnome but Unity.

When trying to maximize a window, I was used to top panel to include the maximized window. It's a bit difficult to explain it for me in english, so I show a picture:

[image]

As you can see there are two top areas there: one with the gnome top panel icons and the second one, right under it with the top panel of the window (where it says "Google - Mozilla Firefox".

How may I put the two of them together (I want to save screen real state) without stating the gnome panel to autohide? (I want it to be visible at all times).

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: That is probably a missing feature, see this: https://solus-project.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=3351

Comment: I just found this (at the link that @pomsky shared): https://github.com/ilgarmehmetali/budgie-pixel-saver-applet but the explanations on the installation are not clear, should I just create a directory and put the files there? It looks like it needs several dependencies...